# Setup Celery on Windows to run Django Cron jobs

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am developing an application in Django 1.3.1 on windowsxp,sp2.

I need to send mails for every period of time. Hence I have chosen celery to do this.

But I'm not getting any proper documentation of celery and how to integrate it with django on windows.

Please send any links guiding me from the very first steps of using celery on windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to call django commands via task manager would be easy to implement
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

so create your mailer command and call it from task manager task